# GDB: find value in whole memory of dump

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, coredump

I have a process coredump on a line like

```cpp
// ptr is boost::shared_ptr<Whatever>
assert(ptr.unique())
```

That is there are two `shared_ptr` referencing same object, but program *logically* expects exclusive ownership. It's logic problem, not memory corruption.

Using gdb I can see address (e.g. 0x001234567890) of pointer, contained in `ptr` and verify that it's `use_count == 2`.

Using hexdump on something like it I can easily find other occurrences:

```bash
$ xxd core2 | fgrep '9078 5634 1200'
114e3e1e0109c 002c 307f 0000 9078 5634 1200 0000  ...
15b8b2ba000d7 ffa2 307f 0000 9078 5634 1200 0000  ...
1618b644000e7 7fa3 307f 0000 9078 5634 1200 0000  ...
```

There is a command `find` in gdb than can search specified region for specified value, but it need correct allocated memory region.

There is a command `info mem` which shows info about memory regions, but it doesn't work for coredumps.

Are there other ways to find, where this address/value is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the pointers pointing at a piece of memory, you can use
valgrind and gdb together.

Then from gdb, you can use the monitor command

```
(gdb)  monitor who_points_at <addr> [<len>]
```

to find where are these pointers.

So, if you have 2 references to a piece of memory, who_points_at
should be able to return them.

Note that who_points_at is searching for any 'word aligned' data
that points at the range [addr, addr + len(
So, you might find more occurences as e.g. an integer might 'look' like
it is pointing at this memory.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver
and
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands

for more info.

Comment: not a real solution when debugging core dumps. There is nothing to monitor. `"monitor" command not supported by this target.`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or some [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (e.g. compile with `-fsanitize=address` [instrumentation option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). It probably is the easiest way to help finding your bug (assuming your bug is reproducible).

Regarding your original question, recent [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) are [extendable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html) in [Python](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html) (and perhaps in [Guile](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Guile.html)). You might write a script for your needs.

You could also put a watchpoint on the `use_count` field of your smart pointer or pointed object (you may need to disable [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) to ease debugging).

Comment: Sorry for misguidance, but it's not a memory problem.
It seems everything GDB provides for python available in plain GDB so it's not an answer.
Watchpoint may solve the problem, but there are many dynamically created pointers in runtime and problem arise very seldom.